# How to hide my password attribute value from inspect element using IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internet-explorer-9

How to prevent showing my value password from 
inspect element using (Internet-Explorer 9) ?

[Inspect element on my input password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFh1w.png)

My JavaScript code

```
  <input class="class1" type="password" id="Pass" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
```

Comment: Why does your input have the password value to start?

Comment: Easy, don't have passwords outputted in the markup

Comment: I'm sure you can't. Cause people can change the input type using the inspector to text and it will show the password anyway. Even in Lastpass you are able to show the password, even if the permissions don't allow you to, just by editing the input type using the inspector.

Comment: Can you further explain what the issue is. Once you type the password in you can inspect it with developer tools?  Ok, well you knew it anyway right, so why is that a problem?